# Locking between transactions in java if two transactions process similar data

Tags: java, concurrency, transactions, ejb-3.1

Is there a possibility to share objects (or some kind of data) between transactions in java?

I've got two (or more) transactions, which should save some data in database. There is unique definition in table for two strings. My defined object has multiple fields and two of them corresponds with two unique fields in the database.
Unfortunately I can't change anything in the database.

I'm thinking about Set, which stores objects with two fields. Any other transaction checks, if object with specific fields exists ant if it does, transaction should wait for specific time. Other transactions should be processed concurrently, only transaction with shared object should wait or be locked for specific time.
But how to share such object between transactions?

This is important, because all requests should be stored in database.
Now I've got Unique constraint violation - if two transactions want to save data in the same time.

The code below contains the most important parts:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class MainStateless  {

    @Override
    protected void processMessageRecord(MyReport report) {
        new DelegateImpl().handleReport(report);
    }
}

public class DelegateImpl {

    @EJB
    private MyImportService myService;

    public void handleReport(MyReport report) {

        try {
            final MyResult result = translateReport(report);
            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                handleReportWithErrors(result);
            } else {
                //Here should be creation of new object with two unique fields (based on result)
                //if object does not exist in shared set, insert it and process as usual. At the end of transaction remove it from the set.
                //if object exists, sleep for some time and then check again.
                myService.saveImportedReport(report);
            }
        } catch (PersistenceException e) {
            log.error("handleReport() persistence exception thrown: ", e);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            log.error("handleReport() runtime exception thrown: ", e);
        }
    }
}

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class MyImportService {

    public void saveImportedReport(MyData data) {
        //Some checks
        saveImported(data); // <- some small logic and save into database 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example ? Also it's unclear what you do when a transaction is waiting, until what ?

Comment: Until object does not exist in set (removed when transaction ends).
Of course it is only my thoughts and maybe there is simplest solution.